# How can Blender in 3.0 add in between frames automatically

Tags: animation

Is there a way Blender can add frames in between other frames, so I don't have it do it manually?

[image]

Comment: i am not sure what you mean. Do you want all keyframes be "filled up" between 1 and thirty? if yes, i don't think this is possible. But of course you could do it with python.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In object mode go to Object menu > Animation > Bake action.

[image]